# Simple JSON request in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

I have the following json

```
country_code({"latitude":"45.9390","longitude":"24.9811","zoom":6,"address":{"city":"-","country":"Romania","country_code":"RO","region":"-"}})
```

and i want just the country_code, how do i parse it?

I have this code

```
<?php
$json = "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback";
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);

var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile));
?>
```

and it returns NULL, why?

Thanks.

Comment: After you do `file_get_contents`, what is the value of your `$jsonfile` variable?

Comment: do a `var_dump($jsonfile)` and add the output the the question

Comment: var_dump($jsonfile) = string(144) "jsonpCallback({"latitude":"45.9390","longitude":"24.9811","zoom":6,"address":{"city":"-","country":"Romania","country_code":"RO","region":"-"}})"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

You just need json not jsonp.
You can also try using  `json_decode($json, true)` if you want to return the array.

Comment: Excellent. This is the kind of simple solution I've been searching high and low for. Thank you so much for your simple answer.

Answer (score 5):

you're requesting jsonp with `http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback`, which returns a function containing JSON like:

```
jsonpCallback({"latitude":"44.9718","longitude":"-113.3405","zoom":3,"address":{"city":"-","country":"United States","country_code":"US","region":"-"}})
```

and not JSON itself. change your URL to `http://api.wipmania.com/json` to return pure JSON like:

```
{"latitude":"44.9718","longitude":"-113.3405","zoom":3,"address":{"city":"-","country":"United States","country_code":"US","region":"-"}}
```

notice the second chunk of code doesn't wrap the json in the `jsonpCallback()` function.

Comment: what?? i never heard about that, so that's not a json? it looks like one

Comment: @RowMinds Does `jsonpCallBack({"a":1})` look like JSON to you?

Comment: @RowMinds it's json, just with a bit of extra data that PHP doesn't understand.

Comment: <?php
 $json = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
 $jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);

 echo "<br>";
 print_r(json_decode($jsonfile));
 
 echo $jsonfile['country_code'];
 echo $jsonfile->$country_code;
 ?>  this might help me but it wont work

Comment: @RowMinds "it won't work" is not a PHP error message, what won't work about it?

Comment: <?php
 

 $json = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
 $jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);
 $jsonobject = json_decode($jsonfile);
 echo $jsonobject->latitude; //displays mike
 
 // ERROR : Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$country_code in D:\xampp\htdocs\wikijojo\jsondecode.php on line 7

 ?>

Comment: i think the parsing don't get to the country .. i think i need a foreach something ...

Comment: @RowMinds, `country_code` in under `address` use `$jsonobject->address->country_code` to get there...

Answer (score 0):

The website doesn't return pure JSON, but wrapped JSON. This is meant to be included as a script and will call a callback function. If you want to use it, you first need to remove the function call (the part until the first paranthesis and the paranthesis at the end).

Comment: i can replace jsonpCallback( and ) with whitespace .... but it will kill my procesor

Comment: If you use an efficient method (for example, the substring method) the time taken to remove the callback part of the string is negligible compared to the time the http request (to get the JSON file) takes.

Answer (score 0):

If your server implements `JSONP`, it will assume the callback parameter to be a `JSONP` signal and the result will be similar to a JavaScript function, like

```
jsonpCallback("{yada: 'yada yada'}")
```

And then, `json_decode` won't be able to parse `jsonpCallback("{yada: 'yada yada'}")` as a valid JSON string

Comment: yap, may be... did u check the diff between that url and http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback ?? they are very different

Answer (score 0):

You are being returned JSONP, not JSON. JSONP is for cross-domain-requests in JavaScript. You don't need to use it when using PHP because you aren't affected by cross-domain-policies.

Since you are getting a string from the `file_get_contents()` function you can do a replacement of the `country_code(` text (this is the JSONP specific part of the response):

```
<?php
$json = "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback";
$jsonfile = substr(file_get_contents($json)), 13, -1);

var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile));
?>
```

## Note

This works but JKirchartz's solution looks better, just request the correct data rather than messing around with the incorrect data.

Comment: @RowMinds Using `substr()` will create unnecessary overhead since you can just request the correct data to begin with. But it's not going to "kill" anything, it's a pretty lightweight thing to do.

Comment: <?php
 $json = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
 $jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);

 echo "<br>";
 print_r(json_decode($jsonfile));
 
 echo $jsonfile['country_code'];
 echo $jsonfile->$country_code;
 ?> this might help me ... but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

If `country_code(` along with closing parenthesis are include in your json, remove them.
This is not a valid json syntax: [json](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in this situation, using the correct URL to access the API will return pure jSON.

`"http://api.wipmania.com/json"`

A lot of people are providing an alternative to the API in use, rather than answering the OP's question, so here is a solution for those looking for a way of handling jSONp in PHP.

First, the API allows you to specify a callback method, so you can either use Jasper's method of getting the jSON sub string, or you can give a callback method of json_decode, and modify the result to use with a call to eval. This is my alternative to Jasper's code example since I don't like to be a copy cat:

```
$json = "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=json_decode";
$jsonfile eval(str_replace("(", "('", str_replace(")", "')", file_get_contents($json)))));

var_dump($jsonfile);
```

Admittedly this seems a little longer, more insecure, and not as clear to read as Jasper's code:

> ```
> $json = "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback";
> $jsonfile = substr(file_get_contents($json)), 13, -1);
>
> var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile));
> ```

Then the jSON `"address":{"city":"-","country":"Romania","country_code":"RO","region":"-"}` tells us to access the country_code like so:

```
$jsonfile->{'address'}->{'country_code'};
```