# How to call a PHP page from a javascript page using express functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, express

I'm trying to display a php page using javascript with express functions. An example code:

```
    var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

I have a php page with html and javascript functions that displays different data from database and I'm not sure how to call the page from the javascript file. I tried putting it in script tags on the php page but how do I then execute the output of the php page in the res.send();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting things wrong. You can't *load* your express code into your PHP or vice versa (in fact you can, but it would be too much work).

To make your PHP code *talk* to your express/node code, you should create an interface between them. I think a RESTful interface would be the easiest one to build. The code you've provided is already a RESTful interface.

Then, in your PHP code (alongside with HTML and client-side JavaScript), you can

- make an XHR or Ajax request to the express/node route (but you'll need to send a json, which is not so different from what you got: `res.json({hello: 'Hello World'})`. More about Express json response [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json)).
- Or, you do use a JSON request from PHP, which you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930434/simple-json-request-in-php).

EDIT:
Ok, here is some PHP code:

```
<?php 
$url = "localhost:3000/";  // this should the route you've defined on 
                           // express. the `app.get('/')` part.
$json = file_get_contents($url); 
var_dump(json_decode($json)); 
?>
```

And your express code should be like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.json({hello: 'Hello World'})
})
```

Then, your PHP's `var_dump` should output:

```
{hello: 'Hello World'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, so should the json request in my php code look like this: `<?php
$url = "file.js";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
?` Honestly, I'm a bit confused as I've been on this for a while. If you can, please give an example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was wondering, can I use any npm package with php other than express as I'm working solely on php and sql.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you'll need to use it on client-side (alongside with php) and get rid of node.